# Get Cell value by ID in Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Good day, I set some IDS to some cells in Excel using this:

```
ActiveCell.id = "whateverID"
```

I don't know if those IDs are saved, and now I need to get the Values of those Cells but by ID, I don't have any idea on how to get it done, I need it because I want to get the values of specific cells using their IDs if such cells change their position, hope you understand.

Or if you know a better way to get it done the better.

Answer (score 1):

> I need it because I want to get the values of specific celss using their IDs if such cells change their position, hope you understand.

For that don't use ID's. Name the cell. For example

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Name = "whateverID"
```

Now even if that range moves, you can always use the following to write/read that cell

**WRITE**

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("whateverID").Value = "Something"
```

OR

**READ**

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("whateverID").Value
```

You might also want to read more about [Define named cell references or ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/define-named-cell-references-or-ranges-HP005201536.aspx)